# Constant current in inductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, home-experiment, induction, inductance

When I brought the dc voltage from $25 V$ to $0 V$ . A constant flow of electrons I could see in the inductor. Why is this phenomenon happening ?

When a constant voltage was supplied the inductor circuit shorted. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Magnetic energy was stored "in" the inductor. When you reduce the voltage, the inductor gives back energy as current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief 'classical' description:

In 1820, Hans Christian Ørsted discovered that an electric current through a wire sets up a 'magnetic field' around the wire, in concentric cylinders with the wire as the axis.

[image]

In its simplest form, an 'inductor' is just a piece of wire. For this reason, a DC voltage applied across an inductor is like a 'short circuit', so a steady (DC) current will flow through an inductor which has a constant voltage across it, limited only by the resistance of the wire.

A few years after Ørsted's discovery, Michael Faraday discovered the principle of 'magnetic induction', that is the observation that a *changing magnetic field* produces an 'electromotive force' (emf), that works to *oppose the change*. More precisely, he described the 'law of magnetic induction' mathematically as:

$$emf= -\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

Where $\phi$ is the (changing) magnetic flux which produces an electromotive force (emf, measured in volts) in a wire.

Most inductors consist of wire wound into several 'coils', each carrying the same current, so that the total magnetic flux linkage through the coils is increased by a factor of $N$, where $N$ is the number of coils.

The 'inductance' is defined as the 'constant of proportionality' between the magnetic flux linkage of a coil and the current flowing through it, that is:

$$L = \frac{N\phi}{i}$$

So, by applying Faraday's Law of Induction, the relationship between voltage and current through an inductor can be expressed as:

$$v(t)=L\frac{di}{dt}$$

The inductor 'stores' energy in it's magnetic field, where the instantaneous energy stored in an inductor is given by:

$$w=\frac{1}{2}Li^2$$

So to 'explain' your problem, when a constant voltage (say 25V DC) is applied to an 'inductor', a constant current flows through the inductor. This sets up a constant magnetic field, so there is energy stored in the inductor, but since there is no changing magnetic field, the magnetic flux $\phi$ is constant, there is no 'electromotive force' ($\frac{d\phi}{dt}=0$) across the inductor to counter the applied voltage. The only thing limiting the current is the (low) electrical resistance of the wire that makes up the inductor. That is, the inductor effectively acts as a 'short circuit'.

However, as soon as you 'open the switch' between the DC voltage source and the inductor, you are suddenly trying to change the current to zero. The the magnetic field collapses and energy is returned to the circuit. An electromotive force is generated across the inductor which effectively tries to 'maintain' a current through the wire (Faraday's law), until the magnetic field is zero. Because the switch opens 'suddenly' (very short time), the emf generated across an inductor can be quite large (several hundred volts), which is enough to generate a ionize the atoms in the air and cause a 'spark' across the switch.

Comment: not a spark i could see, but a constant flow of electrons without changing with time.

Comment: When you switch the voltage across an inductor from say 25V to 0V, the current will be maintained but will decay exponentially to zero eventually, with a time constant of $T=L/R$, where L is the inductance (in Henrys) and R the resistance (in Ohms). That is, after a period of time T=L/R, the current will have decreased by 63%. After a eriod of 5 time constants, the current will be effectively zero.